# Android layout issue using Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm developing an android application for Tablet. I have implemented a DialogFragment that look like this:

[image]

The xml layout is defined by this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F7F7F7" >

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/destinatario_messaggio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Destinatario del messaggio"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#888888" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/body_messaggio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Scrivi Messaggio"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:maxLines="5"/>      
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have two problem:

1- Since I'm using tablet, I want that all the spaces available on the left and on the right of my Dialog is filled from the Dialog itself. Even if I have setted in the root View this:

> android:layout_width="match_parent"

my Dialog is floating at center of the Activity, letting a lot of space available on the left and on the right of it.
How can my Dialog occupy all the width available in my device?

2- When the keyboard(IME) appears for editing the `EditText` field my Dialog is thrust upon hiding the top of the Dialog (the Title and the first TextView become invisible). Instead what I want is that the top of the Dialog remains on top and the center of the Dialogis "compressd". It seems like my layout does not adapt itself to the new available space.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" try this, or adjustSize for the second problem or getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); instead of always_hidden attribute, change it to adjustpane

Comment: where I have can specify  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  ?

Comment: i dint mention that u used it anywhere sir, i was just saying try it . Though generally it is a manifest tag, so use the code to adjust the window when the softkeyboard opens

Comment: Sorry @Dhara my question was not correct. I'm asking you where I can put that line.

Comment: if its an activity that you are using you could place it inside the activity tag in android manifest file. Else when you are calling the dialog, just when you create the view or assign the view, write the dialog.getWindow().setSof ... code

Answer (score 0):

For your first part to make the dialog fill in width use.

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```